# Implement custom Android grid view

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have made a custom gridView and a item witch I want to implement in the gridView, but how can I set these custom gridView onCreate inside my HomeActivity class file?

**HomeActivity.java**

```
  public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            // how can I say here that I want to set the gridView from list_holder.xml

        }
    }
```

**list_holder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view_item_block_holder"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_block" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_block.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_block"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/secondaryBackgroundColor">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/secondaryBackgroundColor"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/no_image_available" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/secondaryBackgroundColor"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="video title"
                android:id="@+id/item_block_title"
                android:textColor="@color/textTitleColor"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/item_block_description"
                    android:textColor="@color/textContentColor"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="12-09-16"
                    android:id="@+id/item_date"
                    android:textColor="@color/textContentColor"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            //Here Adapter like
            AdapterDemoGrid adapterDemoGrid  = new AdapterDemoGrid(this);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapterDemoGrid);

        }
    }
```

> Here, Adapter for Custom GridView Make this class :

```
public class AdapterDemoGrid extends BaseAdapter {

        private final Context context;

        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;


        public AdapterDemoGrid(Context context) {

            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            this.context = context;


        }


        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //lastPosition = -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 20;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (view == null) {

                //The view is not a recycled one: we have to inflate

                view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_block.xml, viewGroup, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();


                view.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            return view;
        }


        class ViewHolder {

            /// Item Block views goes here...

        }
    }
```

Hopefully it will help you !!

Comment: that's exactly what I needed!